# How to convert pdf files into JPEG files and save them in ImageField of Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, jpeg, pdf2image

I want to convert pdf files into jpeg files and save them as ImageField in Django.
In my case, I already have pdf files in MyModel and some of them will be converted into jpeg files and saved as jpeg files as ImageField in AnotherModel.

```
pdf_path = MyModel.object.pdffile.path
```

If I use "convert_from_path" provided by pdf2image, I think it is necessary to prepare the path for a jpeg file in advance. However, I don't know how to prepare it before creating each record of ImageField.

Comment: You can use pre save Django signal. in that you can convert the PDF into image and then save it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#pre-save